# Fira code font stuck on bold for vscode, How to fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've use Fira Code for a while and i just got my new computer working,
When installed Fira Code again into VSCODE, The font stuck on bold and i don't know how to get it working as usual.
[This is how it the setting.json looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBvgx.png)

Comment: Please do not use images to represent text content. Instead, copy and paste the text directly into your post. See [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for more information.

Comment: Suggestion noted.

Comment: Not a suggestion. Please [edit] your post to remove the image and replace it with the text  for the reasons I've indicated.

Comment: use a different theme, maybe Aurora has these strings set on bold

Comment: Try to only install the 'normal' weight of Fira Code

Comment: Installing only the 'normal' or 'regular' weight Fira Code did the trick for me as suggested by @Niko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put `Fira Code` in single quotes:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code', sans-serif",
```

Answer (score 8):

*For those that are stuck on this problem in the future:*

I needed to re-install the font with the `variable font weight` (first install the static and then the variable font). You can find those on Google fonts.

After that the font was normal in VS Code.

Hope it works!

Comment: Make sure that you remove the **static** versions.

Comment: Simply reinstalling them works just fine. No need for removal @theking2

Answer (score 2):

You can fix that by installing FiraCode using chocolatey

```
choco install firacode
```

then restart VS Code afterward.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me, I uninstalled the boldface font but then VS Code stuck on the light face font, so I uninstalled that also, only then it worked as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to also install this file after installing those in static folder.

[image: file name]

As for font family setting:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code', monospace"
```

Answer (score 0):

*For those that land here in the future...*

Restarting VSCode should do the trick. That's what worked for me.

**For Reference:**

I am on Windows 10

My settings.json:

`"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code, monospace"`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was experiencing.
You can download Fira Code on Google Fonts (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Code). Then, install each font weight and go to `settings.json`. (`File` > `Preferences` > `Settings` > Search "Font" > Click on `edit on settings.json` under `Editor: Font Ligatures`)

Then, you can *specify the font weight in the name* like this:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code Medium, 'Courier New', monospace",
"editor.fontLigatures": true
```

Make sure to save the change and reopen VSCode. You should see the change.